# set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons in PHPMailer

Tags: phpmailer

On a shared host I have to use PHPMailer to send emails for certain actions. Unfortunately I don't have access to php.ini to customize it to my needs. Therefore I get the following warning when sending an email:

`[warn] set_time_limit() has been disabled for security reasons in .../class.smtp.php on line 338`

The script still works and all e-mails are sent successfully. But I wanted to ask if there is a way to configure PHPMailer so that this warning does not appear?

Comment: I think you might be stuck there. I can see you’re using an old version of PHPMailer, but I think later versions still use the same mechanism, so updating won’t change that. I would recommend switching to a host that provides full VM access anyway.

Comment: Since its only a small online sqlite database for a game, i would not pay for such thing. That's why i choose a free hosting thingy. I didn't like the host, but its more than enough for our needs. Since sending the mails is still working, i filter out that specific warning in my custom error_handler. All other warnings, error, notice message are passing the handler.